# What is the largest number of people that were in the city at the same period?

Tags: data-structures

a problem has been discussed in the class today says :
n paris are given (ai,bi), each pair stands for a human and ai,bi represent his entrance date and exit date from the city for 2019.
the question, what was the largest number of people were in the city at the same period.

I tried to cast the dates to [1,365] (Integers), and insert them entrance to one AVL and the exit dates to another and save pointers from both of them traversing one tree and updating the maximum if needed.
I beileve this soultion is a naive one since it takes O(n^2).

The data-structers that we learend are:
Array,Linked-List,Queue,Stack,Heap,BST,AVL,Heap,Hash-Table,SkipList and Graph.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array for this logic.

Since number of days in the year is fixed, create an array to keep count of number of people in the city in that particular day.

```
count[365] = {0}; //Reset the counter, all entries should be zero.
maxCount = 0;
maxDay = -1;

for(day from 0 to (365-1))
{
    for(i from 0 to (n-1) person)
    {
        if(day >= ai && day <= bi) //Update this check based on whether ai and bi are inclusive or not.
        {
            count[day] = count[day]+1;
            if(count[day] > maxCount) //Keep track of maxCount, if required update it.
            {
                maxCount = count[day];
                maxDay   = day;
            }
        }
    }
}

Output maxDay, maxCount;
```

The time complexity of the above logic is `O(365*n) => O(n)`.